# transaction logging in neo4j community 3.0

Tags: neo4j, transaction-log

I recently installed the community version of neo4j on a linux server. Now I'm trying to verify queries that are running remotely but I can't seem to find any sort of transaction log. Most parameters I find are referencing 2.3 configurations (which have changed) and everything I've read about 3.0 seems to indicate transaction logs are enabled by default. Yet in the log directory, I do not see 'query.log'.

I've tried enabling http and gc logging but neither of these are helpful as I cannot see the actual query that was executed.

Is this something simply unavailable in the community version?

Comment: http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#transaction-logs  Talks about transaction logs like I should be seeing them by default.

Answer (score 2):

Cypher queries logging can be enabled with a single configuration value, to be set in `conf/neo4j.conf`

```
dbms.logs.query.enabled=true
```

If you want to log also the query parameters, you can add a second setting :

```
dbms.logs.query.parameter_logging_enabled=true
```

The first setting will create a `logs/query.log` with log entries like

```
2016-04-29 18:03:31.679+0000 INFO  86 ms: server-session        http    192.168.1.220   /db/data/transaction - CREATE (n {props}) RETURN n - {props: {name: My Node}}
```

As a reference, there is the operations manual as stated in one of the comments, or the `released today` neo4j knowledge base :

http://neo4j.com/blog/faq/